# Linq Join - Argument types do not match

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to run the following query in my Application (Oracle DB via an edmx model). In the DB both fields (which I'm trying to join) in TABKE1 and TABLE2 are simmilar [BENUTZERNR VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL] and in the edmx fie they are both declared as string.

However i always get a "Argument types do not match" error. (I'm using same joins in other queries where the difference is that the joined datatypes are decimal?)

```
    Dim dataObject = (From a In db.TABLE1
        Join p In db.TABLE2 On a.BENUTZERNR Equals p.BENUTZERNR
        Select New TableOneViewModel With {
             .ID= a.ID,
             ...
             .BIBLBENUTZER = New TableTwoViewModel With {
                    .BENUTZERNR= p.BENUTZERNR,
                    ...
                 }
         })
```

Comment: Field you are joining on has same null status? I mean both are not null/null?

Comment: Yes Nullable Flag is set to False for both Fields.

Comment: What is the datatype of BENUTZERNR in table1 and table2?

Comment: In the Oracle DB the Fields are both defined as VARCHAR2 (15 Byte, not nullable) and in the entity they are defined as STRING (not nullable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that is was a typo and that i was missing a datatype declaration on one of my viewmodel properties!

```
Dim dataObject = (From a In db.TABLE1
    Join p In db.TABLE2 On a.BENUTZERNR Equals p.BENUTZERNR
    Select New TableOneViewModel With {
         .ID= a.ID,
         ...
         .BIBLBENUTZER = New TableTwoViewModel With {
                .BENUTZERNR= p.BENUTZERNR,
                .SOMEVALUE= {MISSED THE "p" HERE}.SOMEVALUE,
                ...
             }
     })
```